# Docker container run locally - didn't send any data

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to run a basic flask app inside a docker container. The docker build works fine but when i try to test locally i get

> 127.0.0.1 didn't send any data error.

Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7 

ENV LISTEN_PORT=5000
EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

CMD ["python3","main.py","--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

main.py

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def this_works():
  return "This works..."

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The command to run the container i am using is :

```
docker run -it --name dockertestapp1 --rm -p 5000:5000 dockertestapp1
```

Also command to build is :

```
docker build --tag dockertestapp1 .
```

Could someone help please.

Comment: can you also add the command you are using to run the container?

Comment: Make sure you run the container with the `--net=host` option or use the docker container IP to try and connect

Comment: Amended post above

Comment: @rdas i have used docker inspect to get the IP and tried using http://172.17.0.2:5000/ to access it through the IP but this also fails

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing `--host` parameter while not using the flask binary to bring up the application. Thus, you need to just take the parameter out of CMD in Dockerfile to your code. Working setup:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7 

ENV LISTEN_PORT=5000
EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

CMD ["python3","main.py"]
```

and `main.py`

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def this_works():
  return "This works..."

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

The way you are building the image and bringing up the container is correct. I am adding the steps again for the answer to be whole:

```
# build the image
docker build --tag dockertestapp1 .

# run the container
docker run -it --name dockertestapp1 --rm -p 5000:5000 dockertestapp1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Every Docker Containter has it's own **memory space & network boundaries**.To make a port available to Client Machine ( Your OS ) , you have to do 2 steps :

1. Expose the port
2. Publish the port

**Exposing the Port**

You generally do it by putting **EXPOSE** statement inside you docker file which you had already done

*Now you need to do step 2*

**Publishing the Port**

Use Below Command to do that ( which maps the port of you host machine ( Docker Conainer ) to the client machine .

```
docker run -p client_port:host_port imageName
```

In your case , it would be :

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 imageName
```

*Replace imageName with your Docker Image Name*

Then you can do :

```
localhost:5000
```

Comment: Thank you, i have tried that before but i have been using http link provided when you run the container, being " Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/". Is there a reason this doesnt work but using localhost:5000 does?

Comment: For that can you try docker run -p 0.0.0.0:5000:5000 imageName ? Are you using windows ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using it, flask is only listening on `127.0.0.1` within the container. So the only way that you can reach it is from within the same container.

For the docker image you're using, you shouldn't need to override the default command. Remove this line from your `Dockerfile` and it should work:

`CMD ["python3","main.py","--host=0.0.0.0"]`