# stripe.api_key = os.environ['stripe_key'] error in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, stripe-payments, lightsail-container-service

I am having trouble deploying a flask app to aws lightsail. I am following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/tutorials/serve-a-flask-app/). I am on step **2b**. I added a few of my own files, such as `index.html`, `/templates`, `/static`.

My directory structure is

```
myproject
|
|--static
|--templates   
|   |--my_templates
|   |--index.html         
|   
|--.env 
|--.gitignore
|--app.py
|--containers.json
|--Dockerfile
|--public-endpoints.json
|--requirements.txt
```

I run the command
`docker run -p 5000:5000 flask-container` and receive

```
  File "/app/./app.py", line 7, in <module>
    stripe.api_key = os.environ['stripe_key']
                     ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 685, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'stripe_key'
```

My `.env` file has

```
...
stripe_key='sk_*****'
```

The top of my `app.py` is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os, mysql.connector, stripe, json, jsonify
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
stripe.api_key = os.environ['stripe_key']

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Interestingly, I was trying to deploy this app to google cloud a while ago, and received the same error. The question is still unanswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77934221/file-frozen-os-keyerror-and-timed-out-in-google-cloud).

When I run the app locally with `python app.py`, it works. I am able to navigate, and can even access the stripe hosted page, so the stripe key is there locally.

I read that you should be able to access environment variables in a docker container in python using `os.environ['my_key']`, and that is what I have in `app.py`.
I tried adding the `.env` file in the command line by using

`docker run --env-file .env -p 5000:5000 flask-container`

and this did not produce any command line errors, however, when I went to `localhost:5000`, the browser showed `local host didn't send any data` and below it `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

I tried to research how to add environment variables to lightsail and found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lightsail-container-container.html). I updated my `containers.json` as

```
{
    "flask": {
        "image": ":flask-service.flask-container.5",
        "ports": {
            "5000": "HTTP"
        },
        "Environment": ["stripe_key"]
    }
}
```

After running `docker run -p 5000:5000 flask-container` I received the same `stripe_key` error on the command line above. I know I'd have to somehow insert the value.

I think this ultimately comes down to how to insert environment variables in production. The error first showed up in google cloud, and now it is here in Docker / lightsail. Any help is appreciated.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.12-alpine
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY app.py .
CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

`public-endpoints.json`

```
{
    "containerName": "flask", 
    "containerPort": 5000
}
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Flask==3.0.0; python_version > '3.6'
Flask==2.3.3; python_version < '3.7'
Werkzeug==3.0.1; python_version > '3.6'
Werkzeug==2.3.7; python_version < '3.7'
gunicorn==20.1.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
stripe==7.13.0
jsonify==0.5
```

Comment: You have two problems. The first is in relation to `.env` file sourcing, which you have determined the solution for already - pass in the `-env-file` argument to docker. The second is that you're not copying everything that makes up the app into the container; so it's probably missing files that it depends on.

Comment: In general, for layout, I keep the docker files and related items in the parent folder, and put the app into a sub-directory. That way I can 'copy appdir /app', which is a lot easier than remembering everything to copy in. In general it's a 'git clone' of the app for deployment

Comment: I see what you're saying. My docker file is now `... WORKDIR /app COPY appdir . RUN pip install -r requirements.txt CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]`, and in parent directory `myproject`, I just have `Dockerfile` and `appdir`, where `appdir` has the directory structure above. WORKDIR is /app within the container, then `COPY appdir .` says copy the local `appdir` into the current working container directory, which is `/app`, right? I ran `docker build -t flask-container .` then `docker run --env-file appdir/.env -p 5000:5000 flask-container`, but browser shows `localhost didn't send any data.`

Comment: Without code; there's no way of figuring out what's going wrong here. I'm looking at the requirements, and the fact that you're using an alpine-based python container and wonder if trying to make the container base more closely match the local environment might help. There's also the fact that alpine 1.12 is EOL (https://endoflife.date/alpine) - perhaps moving to 3.18/3.19 might improve the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my `Dockerfile`, and now it reads

```
...
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY app.py .
COPY /static ./static
COPY /templates ./templates
COPY .env .
CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

The `local host sent no data` was an issue with my ports, not with my dockerfile; the solution to which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194881/docker-container-run-locally-didnt-send-any-data)